# Unexpected token errors in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a script to change local security policy in windows server. When I run these commands by themselves in a PowerShell prompt, they work fine. However when I run the script I am getting an `"Unexpected token 'PasswordComplexity' in expression or statement."` error.

The problem seems to stem from the fact that the script doesn't seem to be executing the `secedit` command, so the `get-content` lines have no file to edit.

Why is `secedit` not running? I've tried putting the `secedit` command outside of the `if` statement, but get the same results.

```powershell
if ($win_ver -match "Server"){
    #export current secuirty policy
    secedit /export /cfg c:\new.cfg
    start-sleep -s 10
    #Disable Password Complexity
    ((get-content c:\new.cfg) -replace (‘PasswordComplexity = 1′, ‘PasswordComplexity = 0′)) | Out-File c:\new.cfg
    #Disable password expiration
    ((get-content c:\new.cfg) -replace (‘MaximumPasswordAge = 42′, ‘MaximumPasswordAge = -1′)) | Out-File c:\new.cfg
    #disable minmum password length
    ((get-content c:\new.cfg) -replace (‘MinimumPasswordLength = 6′, ‘MinimumPasswordLength = 1′)) | Out-File c:\new.cfg
    #import new security settings
    secedit /configure /db $env:windir\security\new.sdb /cfg c:\new.cfg /areas SECURITYPOLICY
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

PowerShell string literals must be enclosed by either single quotes `'...'`:

```powershell
'string'
```

or double quotes `"..."`:

```powershell
"string"
```

Thus, the `‘` and `′` characters that you are using are invalid and need to be replaced:

```powershell
((get-content c:\new.cfg) -replace ('PasswordComplexity = 1', 'PasswordComplexity = 0')) | Out-File c:\new.cfg
```

---

Note too that string literals enclosed by single quotes will not expand variables.  In other words, this:

```powershell
$var = 123
Write-Host "My number: $var"
```

will output:

```powershell
My number: 123
```

whereas this:

```powershell
$var = 123
Write-Host 'My number: $var'
```

will output:

```powershell
My number: $var
```